# How do you call the result from a logic disjunction or similar?

Tags: boolean, naming-conventions, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

when adding two numbers like `2 + 3 = 5` then `5` is called "sum".
When doing `true AND false` or `false NOR true` then what are the names of the result of these operations? Are there any lists or references?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about names of things (maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm sorry. Can someone move my posting to math.stackexchange then or can i do it myself?

Comment: You should do it yourself, it's not like subforums on a bulletin board system :)

Comment: So does that mean i should delete it here and open a new one on math.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expression like "true AND false" is called a [contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction). It always results in false. The truth table of such an expression has nothing but false/zero values as output. An alternative term is [paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox).

The opposite is called [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29), an expression or formula which always results in true.